# MVC Helper Like BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

When I write this code below in my MVC 4 Web Project

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private class Table : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _writer;
        public Table(TextWriter writer)
        {
            _writer = writer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _writer.Write("</table>");
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable BeginTable(this HtmlHelper html, string id)
    {
        var writer = html.ViewContext.Writer;
        writer.Write(string.Format("<table id=\"{0}\">", id));
        return new Table(writer);
    }
}
```

I can use like this,

```
@using(Html.BeginTable("abc"))
{
    @:<th>content etc</th>
}
```

But I dont want to using starts with `Html`

Example, I want to use like this same project,

```
@using(HtmlExtensions.BeginTable("abc"))
{
   @:<th>content etc</th>
}
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: What's the HtmlExtensions class Namespace?

Comment: It just a example, we can call 'Apple', 'Orange' etc. I want to write code like this, because I dont want to my own methods group in Html.

Comment: Curious, why do you want to call it without using it as an extension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the HtmlHelper as parameter, so you have to obtain a reference to a HtmlHelper somehow. For example if you're in a view:

```
@{
    var helper = Html
    HtmlExtensions.BeginTable(helper,"abc")
}
```

You can create a new instance by calling `new HtmlHelper(...)` but then you'd have to supply all parameters, such as ViewContext and so on

Comment: I wrote like you say but I have a error  `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at this line of `var writer = html.ViewContext.Writer;`

Comment: Oh sorry, you're using the writer, I'll update my answer

Comment: If I'm wrong using `writer` please tell me, I can change my code with new one. And really thanks

Comment: I solve this proble like this, `@using (HtmlExtensions.BeginTable(Html,"id"))
{
  <p>content</p>
}` and really thanks for your attensions :)

Comment: But Is it possible, not send `helper` parameters from cshtml page to cs file. Only send id, cshtml to cs? Like `HtmlExtensions.BeginTable("abc")`